# Laravel - Get Groupby Key

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

is there a way to get grouped key in php ?
I've a query as below, wish to get the user key .

```
 $item_list = DB:table('user_orders');
 foreach($item_list->groupBy('user_id') as $user)
 {
   // get group by
   $user_id = $user->key();
 }
```

Comment: I think you're looking foor `order by`, no?

Comment: what do you mean by key here?